# Difficult integral?

Tags: calculus, integration

There's an integral I've no idea how to solve. Even Wolfram|Alpha gives a very odd result.
$$\int \frac{\sqrt{1 - x^2} + \sqrt{1 + x^2}}{\sqrt{1 - x^4}}dx$$

Comment: What have you tried?  Where did you get stuck?  Where is this problem from?  Did you notice that $1-x^4 = (1-x^2)(1+x^2)$?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Have you tried to take apart the integrand into two fractions? This immediately gives
$$\int \left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + x^2}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - x^2}} \right) \, dx = \sinh^{-1} (x) + \sin^{-1} (x) + C.$$